# Conseguir el valor de un item en un archivo json

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Quiero extraer datos de un archivo json usando Python 3 (PyCharm Edu) e importar el url usando urllib, Quiero obtener todos los items con la llave 'count' y después realizar una suma de todos esos valores. Pero recibo este error, quizás el error sea de que el archivo json está compuesto de una lista de diccionarios. Este es el traceback:

```
num = item['count']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Este es el enlace del archivo json con el que estoy trabajando : [jsonfile](http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_1131694.json)
[image: Traceback]

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import json
import ssl

# SSL Certificate Errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = input("Enter url: ")
print("Retrieving:", url)
uh = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx)
data = uh.read()
print("Retrieved ", len(data), "characters")

info = json.loads(data)
print('User count:', len(info))

theList = list()
print(['comments'])
for item in info:
    num = item['count']
    theList.append(int(num))
Sum = sum(theList)
print("Sum: ", Sum)
```

Comment: @abulafia ya la traducí

Comment: @UltimateDystrom el titulo tambien

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. Toooodo, incluyendo el título, va en español (a menos que sea el nombre de algo!). El código lo compartimos como texto, en preguntas y respuestas, para poder usarlo, probarlo, replicar errores y demás. Gracias por editar tu pregunta y espero que encontremos una respuesta a tu problema muy pronto!

Comment: ok ahorita lo arreglo perdón es mi primer pregunta XD creo que se nota...

Comment: Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes. Y créeme, vas muy bien para ser tu primera pregunta! :)

Comment: ya terminé ahora si gracias por el consejo @Alfabravo lo tomaré en cuenta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu JSON tiene esta pinta:

```
{
  "note":"This file contains the actual data for your assignment",
  "comments":[
    {
      "name":"Harjyot",
      "count":100
    },
    ...
    {
      "name":"Kruz",
      "count":4
    }
  ]
}
```

Y esto es por tanto lo que recibes en la variable `info`. Vemos por tanto que esa variable es un diccionario con dos claves, "note" y "comments", conteniendo la clave "comments" una lista con más diccionarios.

Tienes este bucle:

```
for item in info:
```

Ya que acabamos de ver que `info` es el diccionario completo, estás iterando entonces por ese diccionario. Cuando se itera por un diccionario lo que obtienes son sus claves, de modo que este bucle tuyo se ejecutará dos veces, y la variable `item` tomará el valor `"note"` en la primera iteración y `"comments"` en la segunda. Es decir, en cada iteración `item`  **es una cadena**.

Por eso cuando luego intentas hacer `item['count']` obtienes un error. Siendo `item` una cadena no tiene sentido acceder a `['count']`. Si acaso tendría sentido acceder a uno de sus caracteres con algo como `item[0]` por ejemplo. Por eso el error te dice que *string indices must be integers*.

En realidad tú querías iterar por los elementos de la lista que está dentro de `"comments"`. Ahí sí tendría sentido lo que haces porque en ese caso `item`, en cada iteración, contendría uno de los diccionarios que tienen un campo `"name"` y otro `"count"`.

Por tanto basta en principio cambiar tu bucle por este otro:

```
for item in info["comments"]:
```

Comment: muchas gracias bro, perdón por no haberlo aceptado xd apenas iniciaba y no sabía cómo funcionaban varias cosas, ya he progresado mucho ahorita estoy con java y próximamente entrando a la uni :D te mando un saludo.